# php json_encode return only first row of an array

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing an Android application that makes some request to a server in which I have programmed a database. In the server I work with PHP to make query.
Now I wrote this code to make a query and to push the result into an array that I can use later in "Android part" by using java language.
This is my PHP code:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE user='$myusername'";
$res=mysql_query($query);   
$posts = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($res)) {
  while($post[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
     array_push($posts, $post);
  }
} 
echo json_encode(array('posts'=>$posts));
```

The problem is that when I try to get the result in java I can see only the first row of the result. I'm sure that I have more than 1 row because I tried to print `mysql_num_rows($res)` and the result was bigger than 1.
How can I fix this problem??

Edit.
Just to clarify. I make a call to my server in which I use php from Android AsynTask. In onPostExecute method I make something like this:

```
String res = result.toString();
```

where result is the JSONObject that I obtain from doInBackground method. 
Maybe I'm doing error Here because all your solution give me always the first row of the query's result only.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc()` fetch one row at a time, that is why you use `while` loop to fetch all records. Replace `$path[]` with `$path`

Comment: if I replace $post[] with $post nothing change..

Comment: Stop using `mysql_*` functions. They are removed in PHP 7+ and had been deprecated in previous versions. They are also unsafe and do not support prepared statements. You should instead be using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) functions.

Comment: try `print_r($posts)` after while loop with above changes.

Comment: `$query="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE user='$myusername'";
$res=mysql_query($query);   
$posts = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($res)) {
  while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
     $posts[] = $post;
  }
} 
echo json_encode(array('posts'=>$posts));`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify array here.

Change: `while($post[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {`

To: `while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {`

You can always `var_dump($posts)` after `while` instruction and check if you get what you want.